# Can't find Open when starting npm start

Tags: node.js, npm

When I type npm start to run the server I get an error saying it can't find module OPEN. It calls it in the app.js file. Here is the code file:

```js
const path = require('path');
const open = require('open');
const port = 5000;
const app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/index.html'))
})

app.listen(port, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        open('http://localhost:' + port)
    }
});

/*console.log(msg);*/
```

Should there be a node dependency for this module? Is that why it is failing?

Comment: There isn't an open in https://nodejs.org/api/, are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/open?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `open` to your local node_modules folder, this can be done using npm.

`npm install open --save`

The `--save` flag will add it to your package.json (I presume you have one as you reference using `npm start` which needs a package.json) so that you can just run `npm install` in the future if you ever move the source code, this way it will install all dependencies listed in there.